# Resizing a dynamic bitset in C++ to a length entered by the user

Tags: c++, boost, boost-dynamic-bitset

This C++ program asks the user to enter the length of the bit sequence he/she will enter next. This length variable is named xx, it is of type int. I am using three dynamic bitset with the initial size of 5, these are inpSeq, operSeq and bit. I am resizing the bitsets by 
`inpSeq.resize(xx);` for example. When compiling the program, a very big list of errors appears, I feel I can't paste it here. but I am sure that these errors are all related to this variable xx, the code was compiled fine before using it as a variable to resize the bitset. <s>What is wrong with the way I am resizing the bitset?</s> And can I make the bitsets of the size of inpSeq without asking the user to enter the length of inpSeq bitset?

```
#include <iostream>  //Standard library.
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>    //Library for 10 handling.
#include <vector>    //Variable size array.
#include <algorithm> //We use sorting from it.

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 int y = 0;
 int turnCount = 0;
 int count1 = 0, count0 = 0;
 int xx = 0; 
 boost::dynamic_bitset<> inpSeq(5);
 int polyLoc;
 boost::dynamic_bitset<> operSeq(5);
 boost::dynamic_bitset<> bit(5);
 vector <int> xorArray;
 vector <int> keyReg;
 cout << "What is the legnth of the sequence?";
 cin << xx;
 inpSeq.resize(xx);
 operSeq.resize(xx);
 bit.resize(xx);
 cout << "Enter a bit sequence: \n";
 cin >> inpSeq;
 int seq_end = inpSeq.size() - 1;
 cout << "Enter polynomial:";
 cin >> polyLoc;
 while(polyLoc>0)
 {
  xorArray.push_back(polyLoc%10);
  polyLoc/=10;
 }
 cout << "xorArray is: ";
 for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < xorArray.size(); i++)
 {
  cout << xorArray[i] << " ";
 }
 sort(xorArray.rbegin(), xorArray.rend());
 cout << "\n";
 operSeq = inpSeq;
 keyReg.push_back(inpSeq[0]);
  int x = xorArray[0];
  cout << "x is: " << x << "\n";
  for ( unsigned int  i = 0; i < xorArray.size();  i++)
  {
   cout << xorArray[i] << "\n";
  }
  cout << "bit 3 of initial " << bit[seq_end] << "\n";
  do {
  for (unsigned int r = 1; r < xorArray.size(); r++)
  {
  bit[seq_end] = operSeq[x];
  y = xorArray[r];
  bit[seq_end] = bit[seq_end] ^ operSeq[y];
  }
  operSeq >>= 1;
  operSeq[seq_end]  = bit[seq_end];
  keyReg.push_back(operSeq[0]);
  turnCount ++;
  cout << "--\n";
 }
 while ((operSeq != inpSeq) && (turnCount < 20));
 cout << "Generated key is: ";
 for (unsigned int k = 0; k < keyReg.size(); k++)
  {
  cout  <<  keyReg[k];
  }
 cout << "\n";
 cout << "Bit 1 positions: ";
 for ( unsigned int g = 0; g < xorArray.size(); g++)
 {
  cout << xorArray[g];
 }
 cout << "\n";
 cout << "Key length is: " << keyReg.size();
 cout << "\n";
 for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < keyReg.size(); i++)
 {
  if (keyReg[i]==1)
   {
    count1++;
   }
  else {
    count0++;
  }
 }
 cout << "Number of 0's: " << count0 << "\n";
 cout << "Number of 1's: " << count1 << "\n";
 if ( keyReg.size()%2 ==0)
  {
   cout << "key length is even. \n";
   if (count1==count0)
    {
   cout << "Key is perfect! \n";
    }
  else {
   cout << "Key is not perfect! \n";
    }
 }
  else
   {
  cout << "key length is odd. \n";
   if  ((count1==count0+1) || (count0==count1+1))
    {
   cout << "Key is perfect! \n";
    }
  else {
   cout << "Key is not perfect! \n";
    }
   }
  cin.get();
}
```

Comment: `cin << xx;`  Should be `cin >> xx;`

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. I will delete that part of the question. May you help me on the next part, resizing without asking the user to enter the length.

Comment: Where will you get the length from if it's not from the user?  You could write a function that takes the length as a parameter, and the caller of the function is responsible for the length.

Comment: Ammm, isn't possible to resize the bitset according to the bit sequence itself? I guess I will have to use int as a variable data type, so the user enters the bit sequence into an int variable then convert it to binary with some counter to serve as the length?!

Comment: Well, if you're using ints, then sizeof(int) * 8 would be the maximum number of bits that you will need to store the binary version of the int.  Therefore I don't see the advantage of the dynamic bitset, and instead you would just use a regular bitset<T>.  In any event, dynamic_bitset and bitset has a constructor that takes an integer value and creates a bitset that has bits representing the int value.  Look at the 3 arg dynamic_bitset constructor (ignore the third argument, as it defaults to the allocator to use).  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html

Comment: But regular bitset is unresizable!

Comment: You want to store an int, you know what the maximum size will be, so why resize it?  Just use the maximum size (it isn't a huge value), and just index the bits

Comment: `std::bitset<sizeof(int)*8> mybitset(some_int_value);`  So if the int value is 1024, the bitset will be 10000000000 with the leading bits all 0.  Then you index the bits, just like you're doing now.

Comment: Sorry, I think you haven't made myself clear. What I am thinking about is that the user will enter the bit sequence in int data type, so 110110 in integer data type, to be converted to binary in there image no change. Pardon my ignorance, I am just trying to come up with something useful.

Comment: Then use the string constructor for dynamic bitset.  It's there in the link I sent you.  It is the constructor that takes a `basic_string<blah blah...>` as the first argument.  So if the user enters a binary string (you will need to verify it), then you can construct the dynamic_bitset using that string: `string input; //... dynamic_bitset b(input);`  You need to get a small main() program that you can experiment with that just exercises dynamic_bitset so that you get more familiar with what it can do.  That is what any good programmer would do if they are not familiar with how a class works.

Comment: Why and how to verify the binary string?

Comment: Make sure that the user inputs 0's and 1's.

Comment: How to check? That will be my final question :)